# PHP mysql database two request on same table same time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What if user call two requests, which checks user balance then perform operation on balance. Can it cause any problems? For example those two codes:

```
$user = User::find(1);
if($user['balance']>250) {
    // Here for example long loop
    $user->update([
        'balance' => DB:raw('balance - 100')
    ]);
}
```

And second script doing similiar thing. Can be situation like: in first request if statement is passed , then long loop is executed, and in same time second request runing which has if checking balance and this if executes before `$user->update()` is excuted in first request, so can user pass if statement when he does not have balance?

Comment: You can enclose your code in a database transaction, the functions to use depends on your framework.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be such situation. To avoid this use **LOCK/UNLOCK TABLE**

```
$user = User::find(1);
if($user['balance']>250) {
    User::lockTable(); // method name/use depends on your framework
    // Here for example long loop
    $user->update([
        'balance' => DB:raw('balance - 100')
    ]);
    User::unlockTable();
}
```